# Filling complements of areas with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently implementing something with Python and matplotlib. I know how to draw polygons and also how to fill them, but how do I fill everything *except* the interior of a polygon? To be clearer, I'd like to modify the result below, obtained using `axhspan`'s and `axvspan`'s, by clipping the horizontal and vertical red lines so as to obtain a red rectangle (outside which everything is hatched as it is now):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320311/fill-outside-of-polygon-mask-array-where-indicies-are-beyond-a-circular-boundar) asks (and answers) essentially this question.  Look at 'Edit 2' in the accepted answer.  It describes how to create a vector polygon the size of your plot bounds and then how to create a hole in it to match the shape you want to complement. It does this by assigning line codes that define whether or not the pen draws when it moves.

Here is the portion of the above-referenced post that is relevant to this question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    # Contour some regular (fake) data
    grid = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
    plt.contourf(grid)

    # Verticies of the clipping polygon in counter-clockwise order
    #  (A triange, in this case)
    poly_verts = [(2, 2), (5, 2.5), (6, 8), (2, 2)]

    mask_outside_polygon(poly_verts)

    plt.show()

def mask_outside_polygon(poly_verts, ax=None):
    """
    Plots a mask on the specified axis ("ax", defaults to plt.gca()) such that
    all areas outside of the polygon specified by "poly_verts" are masked.  

    "poly_verts" must be a list of tuples of the verticies in the polygon in
    counter-clockwise order.

    Returns the matplotlib.patches.PathPatch instance plotted on the figure.
    """
    import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
    import matplotlib.path as mpath

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # Get current plot limits
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()

    # Verticies of the plot boundaries in clockwise order
    bound_verts = [(xlim[0], ylim[0]), (xlim[0], ylim[1]), 
                   (xlim[1], ylim[1]), (xlim[1], ylim[0]), 
                   (xlim[0], ylim[0])]

    # A series of codes (1 and 2) to tell matplotlib whether to draw a line or 
    # move the "pen" (So that there's no connecting line)
    bound_codes = [mpath.Path.MOVETO] + (len(bound_verts) - 1) * [mpath.Path.LINETO]
    poly_codes = [mpath.Path.MOVETO] + (len(poly_verts) - 1) * [mpath.Path.LINETO]

    # Plot the masking patch
    path = mpath.Path(bound_verts + poly_verts, bound_codes + poly_codes)
    patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='white', edgecolor='none')
    patch = ax.add_patch(patch)

    # Reset the plot limits to their original extents
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim)

    return patch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The post you refer to is about masking a 2D pixel image.  Even though this could be an approximate solution to the question, the ideal solution would be through vector drawing (not pixel drawing).

Comment: scroll down to 'Edid 2' of the accepted answer, You'll find a vector solution.

Comment: Thanks bpowah! Indeed, the `mask_outside_polygon` function in 'Edit 2' together with some hatching did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the complement of a rectangle, you could instead draw 4 rectangles around it (like the 4 rectangles that are visible in your example image).  The coordinates of the plot edges can be obtained with `xlim()` and `ylim()`.

I am not sure that Matplotlib offers a way of painting the outside of a polygon…