# matplotlib - dashed line between points if one condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to draw a plot. What I want to achieve is to connect points if one condition is met. For instance, if I have a dataframe like the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'dates': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006], 'census_people': [306,327,352,478,250, 566], 'census_houses': [150,200,249,263, 180, 475]}) #I changed the dates from strings to ints
```

I could create plots like this use the following codes:

```
plt.plot('dates','census_houses',data=df[df['dates'] < 2004] ,marker='o',color='orange', linewidth=2)
plt.plot('dates','census_houses',data=df[df['dates'] > 2002] ,marker='o',color='orange', linewidth=2, linestyle = '--')
```

The plot is like the following:

[image]

However, what I truely want is, for instance, use the dashed line to connect points if the `census_houses` is bigger than 250. How to achieve this using matplotlib? Any suggestions and insights are welcomed! Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect can be achieved by applying clipping paths. In this example I suppose the full line completely draws over the dashed line, so only clipping of the full line is needed.

In the example, the special value for the y-axis is set to 220, different colors and very thick lines are used, to better see what is happening. The parameters for `Rectangle((x, y), width, height)` are setting `y` to the desired cut-off value, `x` is some position far left, `width` makes sure that `x + width` is far right and `height` is a large positive number to clip above the line, negative to clip below the line.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688573/matplotlib-set-clip-path-requires-patch-to-be-plotted) has more information about clipping paths.

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def do_clipping(patches, special_y, keep_below=True, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
    height = ymax - ymin
    if keep_below:
        height = -height
    clip_rect = Rectangle((xmin, special_y), xmax - xmin, height,
                          transform=ax.transData)
    for p in patches:
        p.set_clip_path(clip_rect)

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
                   'census_houses': [150, 200, 249, 263, 180, 475]})
plt.plot('dates', 'census_houses', data=df, color='limegreen', linewidth=10, linestyle='--')
plot_patches = plt.plot('dates', 'census_houses', data=df, color='crimson', linewidth=10)
do_clipping(plot_patches, 220)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The solution is well received! I will try to apply your codes to my own problems...