# Plot inside polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gis, polygon

I have a problem, i want to plot an heatmap inside a polygon, now i can plot all but i can't force to plot only the area inside a polygon, any suggestion?
This is the code, thank you all

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
# make up some randomly distributed data
seed(1234)
npts = 200

x=df_heat2.lon.values
y=df_heat2.lat.values
z=df_heat2.Val.values

xi=np.linspace(min(df_heat2.lon.values)-0.1,max(df_heat2.lon.values)+0.1,100)
yi=np.linspace(min(df_heat2.lat.values)-0.1,max(df_heat2.lat.values)+0.1,100)



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))




zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='nearest')
# contour the gridded data, plotting dots at the randomly spaced data points.
#CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')  # B/W
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap='BuPu')

plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar

# plot data points.
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o',c='green',s=5)

plt.title('griddata test (%d points)' % npts)
shapefile2.geometry.boundary.plot(color='red',edgecolor='k',linewidth = 2,ax=ax) 

plt.show()
```

[Map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiMjn.png)

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688573/matplotlib-set-clip-path-requires-patch-to-be-plotted) about how to clip the contour with a polygon.  By the way, instead of `griddata` and `contourf`, you could consider calling `tricontourf(x, y, z, ...)`
 directly with the original `x,y,z`

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect!